# If I want to use chef to install software,what shoud I do on the server machine

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife-solo

I learn chef recently, and I find the tutorial on the Internet,they install the ruby environment and chef before they install software on the server machine.

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev libyaml-dev
cd /tmp
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p125/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
gem install chef ruby-shadow --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

my question is the ruby environment and gem chef is a requirement if I want to install software on the server machine?

Comment: Which tutorial is this?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/339-chef-solo-basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Chef 11, Chef is shipped with [Omnibus Installer](http://docs.opscode.com/install_omnibus.html). This brings (almost) everything that Chef needs, including a ruby environment. So you don't have to install any ruby and you are not supposed to install the Chef gem.

Instead [download chef-client](http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/) and follow the install instructions. Alternatively, you can use this command:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

Comment: Actually Chef client versions back to 10.12 are available through omnibus. But if you are just getting started, you should start with the latest 11+.